# Jmeter: How to map specific variable values from CSV file to specific thread-groups in a test plan

Tags: csv, variables, jmeter

I have a test plan with 12 thread-groups, each one is one test scenario.I want to use unique login credentials for each thread-group. So I've created a CSV file, added CSV Data Config element to each thread-group and selected "All Threads" in "Sharing mode". Whenever I execute the test plan(All thread-groups concurrently) the thread-groups are not taking variable rows sequentially. I expected that the 1st thread-group in the test plan would consider 1st row of variables in the CSV file based on the post: [JMeter test plan with different parameter for each thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823285/jmeter-test-plan-with-different-parameter-for-each-thread)
But it is not happening and I am unable to understand the pattern of variable allocation. Please help me resolve my issue.

My CSV file looks like below:
userName,password,message
userone,sample123,message1
usertwo,sample123,message2
.
.
so on...

Refer below for configuration of CSV Data Config element:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads and thread groups are different things. When you choose "All Threads" in "Sharing mode", it just means that all threads **in the same thread group** will share CSV. Thread groups are always independent.

You have 2 simple options:

1. Use one thread group and control what users are doing with controllers. For example [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) can allow you to control how many threads perform this or other script scenario within the same thread group.
2. Split your CSV so, that each thread group has its own CSV.

And many more complicated options, for example:

3. Use [__CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function, which allows to read one line. That way you can assign each thread group a range of lines to read, rather than reading the entire file.
4. If your usernames and passwords are predictable (e.g. user1, user2, etc), you could use a counter and a range for each thread group.